# R: Extracting values from summary()

Tags: r

I'm using the [urca](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/urca/urca.pdf) package to conduct some calculations on unit roots.
For example, let's use following dataset from the urca package:

```
library(urca)
data(Raotbl3)
attach(Raotbl3)
```

Applying the Augmented Dickey Fuller test looks like:

```
lc.df <- ur.df(y=lc, lags=3, type='trend')
summary(lc.df)
```

In return, we get a summary of all values. However, I want to extract only specific values. The possible fields are here:

```
slotNames(summary(lc.df))
#  [1] "classname" "test.name" "testreg"   "teststat"  "cval"      "bpoint"        "signif"    "model"     "type"      "auxstat"  
# [11] "lag"       "H"         "A"         "lambda"    "pval"      "V"             "W"         "P"
```

Interestingly,

```
ur.df(y=lc, lags=3, type='trend')@teststat 
#             tau3  phi2  phi3
# statistic -2.239 3.738 2.597
```

or

```
ur.df(y=lc, lags=3, type='trend')@cval
#       1pct  5pct 10pct
# tau3 -4.04 -3.45 -3.15
# phi2  6.50  4.88  4.16
# phi3  8.73  6.49  5.47
```

works just fine. However, extracting values from "pval" or "lag" does not work (returns "NULL").

When I looked [here](https://r-forge.r-project.org/scm/viewvc.php/*checkout*/pkg/R/methods-summary.R?root=urca), I discovered that the problem appears with every variable that is "=NULL". Not sure if it's important.

```
setMethod("summary", "ur.df", function(object){
  return(new("sumurca", classname="ur.df", test.name=object@test.name,     
             testreg=object@testreg, teststat=object@teststat, 
             cval=object@cval, bpoint=NULL, signif=NULL, 
             model=object@model, type=NULL, auxstat=NULL, lag=NULL, 
             H=NULL, A=NULL, lambda=NULL, pval=NULL, V=NULL, W=NULL, P=NULL))
})
```

Any idea how to solve this?

Comment: it's stored in that `testreg` slot, you could do `with(as.list(lc.df@testreg$fstatistic), pf(value, numdf, dendf, lower=FALSE))`

Comment: If it's `NULL`, it's `NULL`. Just because the slot is named doesn't mean it contains something.

Comment: Awesome, it works! How did you find out about the structure? I'm asking because I'd also need to include "lag".

Comment: Solved: summary(ur.df(merged_table_type$ks_sum, type = "none", lags = 12, selectlags = "AIC"))@testreg$fstatistic[2] gets *numdf*, which is the lag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get the slots with @ and after that as  usual:

```
summary(lc.df)@testreg$coefficients
summary(lc.df)@testreg$coefficients[-c(1,3),4]
```

Comment: Or `slot(lc.df, "testreg")`